# CoreBluetooth , BLE : couldn't discover peripheral

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, obd-ii, dongle

I have a BLE device (obd2 dongle) that I want to connect to. I can pair with it through "settings" but I can't discover it via `didDiscoverPeripheral` delegate method , any help ?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    _centralManager =[[CBCentralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:nil]; 
    [self scan]; 
}

-(void)scan { 

    NSDictionary *options1 =@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES }; 
    [_centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options1]; 
}

-(void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central{ 
    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) { 
        [self scan]; 
    } 
}

-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {

    [peripheral readRSSI];

    [central connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];

}

-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral { 
    CBPeripheral *peripheral1 =peripheral; 
    NSLog(@"peripheral1 name = %@",peripheral1.name); peripheral.delegate=self; 
    [peripheral discoverServices:nil]; 
}
```

Comment: Is it a Bluetooth Low Energy Device?  Can you discover it with the Light Blue App?  Can you show more code?  Specifically, how you initiate discovery

Comment: Yes , my peripheral is BLE. The weird thing that i could pair my app through "settings" but i can't find it with Blue Light.
This is the rest of the code
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   
    _centralManager =[[CBCentralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
   
    [self scan];
}

-(void)scan{
CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, nil];
    NSDictionary *options1 =@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES };
    [_centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options1];
    NSLog(@"started scanning");
}

Comment: -(void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central{

    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        [self scan];
    }
    
    }

Comment: -(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral{
    
    CBPeripheral *peripheral1 =peripheral;
    NSLog(@"peripheral1 name = %@",peripheral1.name);
    
    peripheral.delegate=self;
    [peripheral discoverServices:nil];
  
}

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code so that it can be formatted properly. If LightBlue can't find your peripheral then there is a very good chance that it is not advertising a BLE service

Comment: `- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     _centralManager =[[CBCentralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self       queue:nil]; [self scan]; } 

    -(void)scan{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, nil]; NSDictionary *options1 =@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES }; 
[_centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options1]; } `

Comment: `-(void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central{ if  (central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) { [self scan]; } }`

Comment: `-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral{ CBPeripheral *peripheral1 =peripheral; NSLog(@"peripheral1 name = %@",peripheral1.name); peripheral.delegate=self; [peripheral discoverServices:nil]; } `

Comment: @Paulw11, code formatted, thanks in advance

Comment: No, you can edit your question and add the code; there is an "edit" link below the question

Comment: So you don't get a call to `didDiscoverPeripheral` at all?  Your code look OK.  The only issue I can see is that you don't store the peripheral you have  discovered/connected to in a property, so a strong reference won't be held and the connection won't go ahead, but if you aren't getting a call to `didDiscoverPeripheral` then you aren't getting that far.  As I said, if LightBlue can't see the peripheral then it is quite possible that it is legacy Bluetooth and not BLE.  Do you have a link to the OBD dongle you are using?

Comment: I have already tried storing my peripheral into a strong property, but still nothing.
Here 's the link to mu Bluetooth dongle (last device)
http://www.continental-automotive.com/www/automotive_de_en/themes/commercial_vehicles/tolling_telematic_solutions/telematics_en.html

Comment: Hmm.  Not much information there.  Based on what you are seeing; LightBlue can't find it and you can pair it from settings, it sounds like a legacy Bluetooth device to me

Comment: @Paulw11, much obliged.

Comment: Just one more question @Paulw11, i have an android device that supports BLE but i can't detect it with Light Blue, could this app discover android peripherals ?

Comment: You need to be running an app that advertises a service on the Android phone for there to be a thing to discover.